# add extra text at the end while exporting table to csv using batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to add constant columns at the end of each column exported to csv from mysql table.

I need something like below after the column;

```
KZ67T;GBR;staff;
MV056;GBR;staff;
NU670;GBR;staff;
```

I am able to export only the plate KZ67T from the table.

```
@echo off
    " C:\ProgramFiles\MYSQL\MYSQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe" mysql -uroot -ppassword  -sN -e "select plate form SWP;" > \output.csv
    pause
    exit
```

Comment: I've not often had a need to use MySQL, but is the syntax not supposed to be `SELECT` `FROM` not `SELECT` `FORM`. _If not it seems a little crazy to have two such similar options!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :sqlout > .\output.csv

exit /b

:sqlout
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
 "C:\ProgramFiles\MYSQL\MYSQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe"
 mysql -uroot -ppassword  -sN -e
 "select plate from SWP;"
') do if not "%%~A" == "" echo %%A;GBR;staff;
exit /b
```

The plate column is read as a row and appends `GBR;staff;`.

The `for` loop handles this and echoes each new row.
The `call` of the label redirects the echoes to the
file `.\output.csv`.

If you prefer `\output.csv` then remove the leading dot.

Type `for /?` and `call /?` for help.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that `for /f "tokens=*"` is **not** the same as `for /f "delims="` ? Not important here, but the first will strip leading spaces from output. Otherwise +1

Comment: @LotPings, I knew. I changed it to satisfy any concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@echo off
    " C:\ProgramFiles\MYSQL\MYSQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe" mysql -uroot -ppassword  -sN -e "select plate form SWP;" > \output.csv
    echo KZ67T;GBR;staff; >> \output.csv
    pause
    exit
```

Comment: I need to add  only GBR; and staff at the end of each plate, there are 1000 plates from the table

Comment: Sorry, I no longer feel that I understand the question